# php security if no data requested

Tags: php, security

I'm a complete (1 week) php beginner. 
I use php to include html menu, scan server directory for new images/video/text(to be added by the person I do the site for), make thumbnails...

Is there security issues if no data is resquested from the user?

Perhaps something like accessing menu.php and include some code.

Comment: In my eyes this looks o.k. and safe.

Comment: I think this would really depend in how you implemented it and not in the idea you had. BTW, I would recommend that you use some PHP Framework (Laravel?) or a PHP CMS (Wordpress?).